# Signed arithmetic

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm running this piece of code, and I'm getting the output value as (converted to hex) 0xFFFFFF93 and 0xFFFFFF94.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x = 0x91;

    char y = 0x02;

    unsigned out;
    out = x + y;

    cout << out << endl;
    out = x + y + 1;
    cout << out << endl;
}
```

I'm confused about the arithmetic going on here. Is it because all the higher bits in out are taken to be 1 by default? 
When I typecast out to an int, I get the answers as (in int) -109 and -108. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You must have `std::hex` in your code that is missing above.

Comment: ... and read about twos complement

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. I used an online converter because I wanted to check the hex value. The value in decimal was 4294967187 and 4294967188.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a couple of things going on here. One, *char* can be either *signed* or *unsigned*, in your case it is *signed*. Two assignment will covert the right hand side to the type of the left hand side. Using the right warning flags would help, `clang` with the `-Wconversion` flags warns:

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
out = x + y;
    ~ ~~^~~
```

In this case to do this conversion it will basically add or subtract the `unsigned max + 1` to the number to be converted.

We can see the same results using the [limits header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits):

```
#include <limits>

//....
std::cout << std::hex <<  (std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max() + 1) + (x+y) << std::endl ;
//...
```

and the result is:

```
ffffff93
```

For reference the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.17` *Assignment and compound assignment operators* says:

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.

Clause 4 under `4.7` *Integral conversions* says:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

which is equivalent to adding or subtracting `UMAX + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

A plain `char` usually also represents a signed type! Since compatibility reasons with C syntax, this isn't specified further, and may be compiler implementation dependent. You always can make it distinct signed arithmetic behavior, by explicitly specifying the `signed` / `unsigned` keywords.

Try replacing your char definitions like this

```
unsigned char x = 0x91;
unsigned char y = 0x02;
```

to get the results you expect!

See the fully working sample [here](http://ideone.com/y8CBt8).

Answer (score 0):

The negative numbers are represented internally as 2's complement and hence, their first bit is a 1.  When you work in hex (and print in hex), the significant bits are displayed as 1's leading to numbers like you showed.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't specify whether char is [signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/104774). Here they are signed, so when they are promoted to int's, the negative value is used which is then converted to unsigned.  Use or cast to `unsigned char`.